# How to extract IIS configuration?

Tags: iis

I want to extract current configuration from existing IIS Server and transfer it to another Server to configure IIS. If need be I may upsize some memory related parameters. What is the best way to get this done? Should I look up Metabase.xml parameters and write an Mgmt API wrapper to extract the values for each of these parameters? OR Is there a broader set of parameters that I should look up to extract the values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Web Farm` for that,
it allows you to manage the IIS of multiple servers (and more than that).

You can read about it here:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-farm-framework

Comment: Sorry, the servers belongs to different domains not on the same farm. So need a extract transfer approach.